# Add alias to Office 365 Group

Tags: groups, microsoft-office-365

We're trying to add an email alias (with a period, e.g. my.email@domain.com) to a Office 365 Group. Does anyone know if that is possible?

We're trying out the new [Office 365 Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2) in Office 365 and for whatever reason we are unable to have a period in our Group Id so we've used a dash.

Error: my.email@domain.com

Works: my-email@domain.com

This group id also happens to be the email. And our corporate email naming policy is to not use dashes and to use periods instead. Since on creation we cannot use a period, we thought at least we should be able to create an alias with a period. However I haven't found a way to do that.

Does anyone know the steps that can be taken to add an email alias to an Office 365 Group that contains a period?

For what it's worth, it should be possible because Office 365 automatically added an alias for the onmicrosoft.com domain. e.g. my-email@xyz.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: I think you can use dots rather than dashes but I'd hate to have to debug your future PowerShell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To add an alias to a distribution group or shared mailbox, you can access the
Exchange Admin Center -> recipients -> groups (or shared) -> double click on the object -> email options, then you can click “+” to add an alias to this group (shared mailbox).

And it's all!

Comment: This question is about Office 365 Groups. The Email Options item does not exist for Office 365 Groups.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the comment